# awk | update field number after comparing field from other file

Tags: awk

- **Input File1: file1.txt** 
  MH=919767,**918975**
  DL=**919922**
  HR=919891,919394,919812
  KR=919999,918888
- **Input File2: file2.txt** 
  aec,919922783456,a5,b3,,,asf
  abc,918975583456,a1,b1,,,abf
  aeci,919998546783,a2,b4,,,wsf
- **Output File** 
  aec,919922783456,a5,b3,**DL**,,asf
  abc,918975583456,a1,b1,**MH**,,abf
  aeci,919998546783,a2,b4,**NOMATCH**,,wsf
- **Notes**

  - Need to compare phone number (**Input file2.txt - 2nd field** - initial 6 digit only) within **Input file1.txt - 2nd field with "=" separted)**. If there is match in intial 6 digit of phone number, then OUTPUT should contain 2 digit code from file (Input file1) into output in **5th field**
  - File1.txt is having **single code** (for example MH) for mupltiple phone number intials.

Comment: How much data do you have? Can one of the files fit in memory? Any specific reason you want to use awk only and not perl/python?

Comment: Data can be of approx 100MB in a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `GNU awk`, try the following. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file1.txt file2.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
     FS="[=,]"
     OFS=","
}

FNR==NR {
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        a[$1][$i]
    }
    next
}

{
    $5 = "NOMATCH"
    for(j in a) {
        for (k in a[j]) {
            if (substr($2,0,6) == k) {
                $5 = j
            }
        }
    }
}1
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -F "[=,]" 'FNR==NR { for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) a[$1][$i]; next } { $5 = "NOMATCH"; for(j in a) for (k in a[j]) if (substr($2,0,6) == k) $5 = j }1' OFS=, file1.txt file2.txt
```

Results:

```
aec,919922783456,a5,b3,DL,,asf
abc,918975583456,a1,b1,MH,,abf
aeci,919998546783,a2,b4,NOMATCH,,wsf
```

---

If you have an 'old' `awk`, try the following. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file1.txt file2.txt
```

Contents of script.awk:

```
BEGIN {
     # set the field separator to either an equals sign or a comma
     FS="[=,]"
     # set the output field separator to a comma
     OFS=","
}

# for the first file in the arguments list
FNR==NR {
    # loop through all the fields, starting at field two
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {

        # add field one and each field to a pseudo-multidimensional array
        a[$1,$i]
    }

    # skip processing the rest of the code
    next
}


# for the second file in the arguments list
{
    # set the default value for field 5
    $5 = "NOMATCH"

    # loop though the array
    for(j in a) {

        # split the array keys into another array
        split(j,b,SUBSEP)

        # if the first six digits of field two equal the value stored in this array
        if (substr($2,0,6) == b[2]) {

            # assign field five 
            $5 = b[1]
        }
    }

# return true, therefore print by default
}1
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -F "[=,]" 'FNR==NR { for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) a[$1,$i]; next } { $5 = "NOMATCH"; for(j in a) { split(j,b,SUBSEP); if (substr($2,0,6) == b[2]) $5 = b[1] } }1' OFS=, file1.txt file2.txt
```

Results:

```
aec,919922783456,a5,b3,DL,,asf
abc,918975583456,a1,b1,MH,,abf
aeci,919998546783,a2,b4,NOMATCH,,wsf
```

Comment: Thanks Steve.. Second awk one liner is working perfectly fine

Comment: Could you please explain this to me as well.

Comment: @VipinChoudhary: I've added some comments to the code for you. If anything is not clear please let me know. Also, more information about the use of 'Multi-dimensional' arrays can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays.html). HTH

Comment: For interests sake, the `gawk` solution up top uses what's called a 'true multi-dimensional' array. But if the solution didn't work for you, you're probably using another `awk`.

Comment: I am really thankful to you for the too clear explanation.. it really helped me in understanding. Thanks Steve.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) A[$i]=$1
    next
  } 
  {
    $5="NOMATCH"
    for(i in A) if ($2~"^" i) $5=A[i]
  } 
  1
' FS='[=,]' file1 FS=, OFS=, file2
```

Comment: Thanks Scrutinizer, this script is working fine. Thanks to you too.